# Automatically Deleting Test Lead records created by Ghost Inspector on Salesforce

Tags: trigger, delete

We have deployed ghost inspector to automatically create leads to check for website downtime. The leads are created with a random email address that begins with "ghostinspector+XXXXX@gmail.com".

How can I create some sort of a trigger to automatically delete those records because they are increasing our leads counts and conversion rates.

I have read something about apex triggers etc.  Can you guide to the right direction.  We use Salesforce classic if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: A trigger may or may not help you, depending on how Ghost Inspector checks for success. To see if the trigger does work, have you tried implementing it? Where are you stuck? You can take a look at [Triggers trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) for a tutorial

Comment: As with identigral, you could also use a lightning flow to delete (sync or scheduled)

Comment: Lets take Ghost Inspector out of equation for a moment. Whenever a New lead is generated, how can I delete any new lead which has "ghostinspector" (eg: "ghostinspector+XXXXX@gmail.com") in email address

Comment: It's easier to start building Flows compared to Apex triggers.  Check the Trailhead resources like [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-flows-with-flow-builder) for tutorials.